# Reset \lstset Style

Tags: listings, lstdefinestyle

I define a `\lstdefinestyle` in my document that looks something like this:

```
\lstdefinestyle{examplestyle}{
  backgroundcolor=\color{green},
  commentstyle=\color{blue},
  keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{black},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  language=python,
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  breaklines=true,
  keepspaces=true,
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=true,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=examplestyle}
```

How can I reset the style set with `\lstset` back to the default values? I tried the command `\lstset{style=}`, but only the language is reset, line numbers, background color, etc. remains.

Comment: It is better to use a style in confined areas such as in `\begin{lsstlisting}[style=...]` or in the definition of `lstlisting` like envs, see the `listings` manual as to how these are defined.

Comment: Okay thank you, then I will fix it this way.